# Simplify $\frac{(\cos \frac{π}{7}-i\sin\frac{π}{7})^3}{(\cos\frac{π}{7}+i\sin\frac{π}{7})^4}$

Tags: complex-numbers

Simplify
    $$\frac{(\cos \frac{π}{7}-i\sin\frac{π}{7})^3}{(\cos\frac{π}{7}+i\sin\frac{π}{7})^4}$$

I used de Morvre's theorem to get to

$$\frac{(\cos \frac{3π}{7}-i\sin\frac{3π}{7})}{(\cos\frac{4π}{7}+i\sin\frac{4π}{7})}$$

How do you simplify from here? 
The answer is meant to be $$\sin9\theta + i\cos\theta$$

Comment: What is $\theta$ in your answer?

Answer (score 2):

Hint. $e^{ix} = \cos x + i \sin x = \cos (-x) - i \sin (-x)$

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

$\cos\frac{3\pi}{7}=-\cos\frac{4\pi}{7}$, $\quad\sin\frac{3\pi}{7}=\sin\frac{4\pi}{7}.$

$$
\frac{(\cos \frac{3π}{7}-i\sin\frac{3π}{7})}{(\cos\frac{4π}{7}+i\sin\frac{4π}{7})}=\frac{(-\cos\frac{4π}{7}-i\sin\frac{4π}{7})}{(\cos\frac{4π}{7}+i\sin\frac{4π}{7})}=-1.
$$

Answer (score 0):

$$
\frac{\cos(3\pi/7) -i \sin(3\pi/7)}{\cos(4\pi/7) + i \sin(4\pi/7)} = \frac{e^{-i3\pi/7}}{e^{i4\pi/7}}=e^{-i(3\pi/7+4\pi/7)}=e^{-i\pi}=-1
$$